# Pandas: Merging two dataframes at different sampling rates without duplicating values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different Pandas `DataFrame`s one sampling at 60 ms and the other at 1s.

`tobii_df`:

```
    datetime, col1 
0  2017-08-24 12:59:00.753, 1.3  
...
1  2017-08-24 12:59:13.753, 7.2 
2  2017-08-24 12:59:13.773, 6.1 
3  2017-08-24 12:59:13.793, 5.1 
4  2017-08-24 13:00:00.813, 5.4
```

`hr_df`:

```
    datetime, col2 
0  2017-08-24 12:59:00, 60
1  2017-08-24 13:00:00, 64
2  2017-08-24 13:01:00, 63 
3  2017-08-24 13:02:00, 67 
4  2017-08-24 13:03:00, 61
```

I would like the end result to be

```
    datetime, col1, col2
0  2017-08-24 12:59:00.753, 1.3, 60
...
1  2017-08-24 12:59:13.753, 7.2,
2  2017-08-24 12:59:13.773, 6.1,
3  2017-08-24 12:59:13.793, 5.1,
4  2017-08-24 13:00:00.813, 5.4, 64
```

This code merges the two dataframes but have the value 60 replicated on several readings of the df1.

```
hr_df = hr_df.sort_values(by='datetime')
tobii_df = tobii_df.sort_values(by='datetime')
hr_df = hr_df.set_index('datetime')
tobii_df = tobii_df.set_index('datetime')

merged_df = pd.merge_asof(tobii_df, hr_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_', ''))
```

I have also tried

```
hr_df = hr_df.set_index('datetime')\
    .reindex(tobii_df.set_index('datetime').index, method='nearest')\
    .reset_index()
merged_df = pd.merge(tobii_df, hr_df, on='datetime')
```

This also have created a duplicates on each readings of `tobii_df`. The end result of both codes are similar to this:

```
    datetime, col1, col2
0  2017-08-24 12:59:00.753, 1.3, 60
...
1  2017-08-24 12:59:13.753, 7.2, 60
2  2017-08-24 12:59:13.773, 6.1, 60
3  2017-08-24 12:59:13.793, 5.1, 60
4  2017-08-24 13:00:00.813, 5.4, 64
```

Comment: From your last solution, you could remove duplicated element in `col2` ? If you have a problem in removing duplucated element, you can add an index column for `hr_df` and remove duplicated index instead of duplicated value.

Comment: @Thomas The main issue here is that the merge process copies the value of `col2` to a wide range of rows in `col1`. I just want it copied once.

Comment: that's why I propose you to replace duplicated element by NaN for example